# Actionscript: Access of possibly undefined property id

Tags: macos, actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript, air

I have a desktop Actionscript project.

The following line

```
_rXML.part.instrument.(@id = instruments[@id]);
```

Produces the error

> Access of possibly undefined property id

What is odd is that this error only occurs on OSX. The exact same code in Windows runs fine.

The Mac is running InteliJ / Catalina and Windows is running FB 4.6. Both are using SDK v32 and I think this error comes from the compiler so the different environment should not matter. I also think that the as Catalina only supports 64bit a different runtime is used.

How can I fix this issue and why does it only occur on OSX?

Comment: Is it possible that case sensitivity is involved, like "id" vs "ID"?

Comment: Also, did you check in your xml that all instruments do have an "id" attribute?

Comment: I am sure the variables are named correctly. I can trace the id and get a result for every relevant part of the XML file. The only way to make this work in OSX is to re-write the line to use a loop. Further to the above, this line also fails in that the output is totally different between Win/OSX 

rXML..note.(vNo = Math.max(vNo, vo));

Again, this code works on 32/64bit Air on Windows but fails on 64bit under OSX. If you see both lines utilize XML data type, so I think 64bit under OSX handled XML data differently.